# IOS/Xcode: Best place for login fork in app

Tags: ios, xcode, authentication, appdelegate

Where is best place to put login fork for IOS app?

I've seen it suggested to place it in appdelegate.  However, I'm wondering if this creates unneeded overhead, doesn't always get triggered or, in general, if there might be a better option.

Is putting it in applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions best place for it as in following or should it be somewhere else?

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"loggedin"]) {
            // go to login screen
            NSLog(@"not logged in");

            [self presentWelcomeInterface];
        } else {
            // go to main screen
   NSLog(@"logged in");
           [self presentMainInterface];
        }
      - (void)presentMainInterface
    {
        self.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateInitialViewController];
    }
    - (void)presentWelcomeInterface
    {
        UIViewController* rootController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];

        UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
        self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I use is to have a root view controller which decides which segue to perform depending on the login status:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if([UserDefaultsUtility onboardingComplete]){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:ShowMainScreenSegue sender:self];
    }else{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:ShowOnboardingSegue sender:self];
    }
}
```

By using this approach you partition the code nicely for better maintainability.

As a bonus, this root view controller could have the launch image as it's content:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.layer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:[self activeLaunchImage]].CGImage;
}

- (NSString *) activeLaunchImage
{
    NSString *launchImage;
    if  ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) &&
         ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 480.0f)) {
        launchImage = @"LaunchImage-700-568h";
    } else {
        launchImage = @"LaunchImage-700";
    }
    return launchImage;
}
```

By doing this, the user won't even notice the root view controller as the transition will be done seamlessly towards the right place depending on the login status.

**P.S:** The active launch image method needs to be modified if you want to get the specific launch image for the two iPhone 6.